# $\cos(z+iz)=0$ and $e^{z^2}=0$ complex roots

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

Find the solution(s) for $\cos(z+iz)e^{z^2}=0$, where $z$ complex

First, let's look at $e^{z^2}=0$ and assume that there exists such an $z$ so that the equation is satisfied, then

$|e^{z^2}|=0$ which thereby means $e^{\operatorname{Re} z^2}=0$ which is not true as $\exp(x)$ is strictly positive for all real numbers.

Second, and the one I'm having trouble with: $\cos(z+iz)=0$, I used the addition theorem and then substituted it for the exponential function. Eventually I arrive at:

$e^{2iz+2z}=-1$ and I don't know how to continue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $\cos(\alpha z)=0\implies z=\frac{(2n-1)\pi}{2\alpha}$

Comment: Oh ok, we've never been through that. Any idea on how I could solve the equation $e^{2iz+2z}=-1$

Comment: One idea is to write $z=x+iy$ and rewrite the exponent in terms of it's real and imaginary parts. By comparing the absolute values in both sides of the equation you can obtain a relation between $x$ and $y$, eliminating one of the variables. You can then compare the arguments to obtain an expression for the solutions.

Comment: There's a little mistake in your comment. The points where $\cos x = -1$ are of the form $\pi+2k\pi$ where $k$ runs over the integers. So the expression for $b$ is $4b=\pi+2k\pi$. But aside from this, your reasoning is correct. It's important to note that if you proceed as @Mark Viola suggested, you will end up with a slightly different expression, but which gives exaclty the same set of soutions.

Answer (score 1):

$e^{z^2}=0$ has no answer but for the second one we have$$z(1+i)=k\pi+\dfrac{\pi}{2}$$or$$z=(k\pi+\dfrac{\pi}{2})\dfrac{1-i}{2}$$